# How to Maintaining a social networking website?

Tags: social-networking

I have searched stack overflow and found a question that is relevant to what i need to ask. [Managing a social networking website what should i do and how ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931573/managing-a-social-networking-website-what-should-i-do-and-how).

I have a small social networking site that i have built. It's not a big thing, but it just provides the best of what it is built for. Now i need to add new features, improve the code, fix bugs and so on in the code. The site is live, and how do i make these changes to the code when the site is live. What if i overwrite a code file that is being accessed by a user or many user's of the site.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for SO, so you may get downvoted.  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com may have additional information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid overwriting or losing code important to your project, it's a good idea to use some sort of [source code versioning software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software).  **Git** and (and [Github](http://github.com)) is one of the more popular products out there right now.

Using versioning software will allow you to add new features, and improve code with out the risk of losing everything, as all changes are tracked, and can be undone if necessary.